# Adding a column (SE Beta) in gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

Is it possible to get a column for standard error of beta like beta, 95% CI, and p-value in the gtsummary package in R?

I searched the online documentation here: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_regression.html

I looked for "error" and reviewed all the options.

Answer (score 0):

The gtsummary tables have a number of hidden columns, and the standard error is one of them. You can use the `modify_column_unhide()` to have the column shown. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.2'

tbl <- lm(mpg ~ hp + factor(cyl), mtcars) |> 
  tbl_regression() |> 
  modify_column_unhide(columns = "std.error") 

as_kable(tbl) # convert to kable to display on stack overflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **Beta** | **SE** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hp | -0.02 | 0.015 | -0.06, 0.01 | 0.13 |
| factor(cyl) |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | — | — | — |  |
| 6 | -6.0 | 1.64 | -9.3, -2.6 | 0.001 |
| 8 | -8.5 | 2.33 | -13, -3.8 | 0.001 |

```r
# you can inspect the hidden columns by printing the table body `tbl$table_body`
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>